# При border: none - table cell уменьшается, как исправить?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, table

Есть таблица:

```css
.button {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #DADADA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #323232;
  transition: all .3s;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
  border: none;
  background: #323232;
  color: white;
}

.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

thead,
tbody,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
  transition: background .2s;
}

th {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  padding: 12px 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

td {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #323232;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
}

tbody tr:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Название блока</th>
      <th>Статус</th>
      <th>Действия</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Хедер - шапка сайта</td>
      <td>Опубликовано</td>
      <td>
        <button class="button">Редактировать</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

При наведении на кнопку - `table cell` уменьшается, это из-за того, что у ячейки задан padding, так же как и у кнопки. Но суть в том, что **фиксированную высоту задавать нельзя**, так как таблица полностью динамическая.

**Как избавится от этого эффекта ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в отсутствующей границе. Добавьте в .button:hover `border: 1px solid transparent;`

```
.button:hover {
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* this */
    background:
    #323232;
    color:
    white;
}
```

Comment: А дизайнеру мне что сказать ?)

Comment: Ааа, блин вот так, умно, спасибо

Comment: так и сказать: добавь границу))